# Retrieving URL from WCF WebInvoke POST Service

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a WCF REST service that is used to POST a file stream to. I need to send a parameter in the URL for the service such as the file name. I have no control over the service providing the file other than dynamically providing the URL - which is why I need to use the URL to include the file name and cannot include it in the stream data itself.

Is there a way to retrieve the URL from within the WCF service so that I can parse out the file name?

My method currently looks like this:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/UploadRecording", Method = "POST")]
        public void UploadRecording(Stream input)
        {
            ...
        }
```

I need something more like:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/UploadRecording/{FileName}", Method = "POST")]
        public void UploadRecording(Stream input)
        {
            ...
        }
```

And then be able to parse the FileName out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadRecording/{FileName}", Method = "POST")]
public void UploadRecording(string FileName, Stream input)
{
    ...
}
```

Se details at [WCF "Raw" programming model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It should be in WebOperationContext.Current